# Javascript Inheritance: How can we inherit object and function where object is created from function using new operator and has prototype functions

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have fucntion A:

```
function A() {} 
A.prototype.fnA() = function(){}
```

create a object:

```
a = new A()
```

I have function B:

```
function B() {}
B.prototype.fnB = function(){}
```

I wish to inherit object `a` with instance of `B` so that new instace created will have proto functions of both `A` and `B`.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code does what you need:

```js
'use strict';

function A() {
    // ...
}

A.prototype.fnA = function () {
    console.log('Running fnA()');
};

function B() {
    // ...
}

B.prototype = new A();
B.prototype.fnB = function () {
    console.log('Running fnB()');
};

var b = new B();
b.fnA();
b.fnB();
```

Comment: This helps. But how can we achieve same with Object.create functions